# Android: Get an instance from a service running

Tags: android, service

I have a service running in background. I started it from an Activity, but I want to recover an instance of that service from another activity (in the same app) in order to call one method.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one instance of the service, at most. You cannot have two instances. Hence, just have the second activity bind to the service ("recovery an instance").